# Boostrap multi date range picker closes on clicking on Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I have used the Bootstrap multi date range picker, everything works fine. I have the date picker in the middle of the page, on clicking on the date picker the picker opens below the text-box

But it is partially hidden and the scrollbar appears in the page and when i try to click and scroll the page, the focus from the text-box is removed and causes the date picker to be hidden.

Is is possible to prevent the date picker from closing when clicking on the scrollbar and other scroll events?

What I have tried is to find the click on the scrollbar and prevent the picker from closing, but it does not help much.

Is there a simple way to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance, help much appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code ! A fiddle illustrating the problem would be great

Answer (score 0):

Inside the JS file, there is a function that execute when the click is performed outside the date-picker area. Have added the below code to check whether the click is performed on a scroll bar or not and executed the function.

Use this check on the outsideClick function

```
 if (!(e.target == $('html').get(0)))
```